# using LINQ convertAll when some conversions may be null

Tags: c#, linq

i have the following code

```
          people = positions.ConvertAll(r=> r.Person).ToList();
```

but in some cases "Person" is going to be null, in these cases i simply don't want to add them into the converted collection (i dont want null items)

what is the best way of achieving this.  Can you have a conditional convertall ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
people = positions
.Where(r => r.Person !=null).ToList()
.ConvertAll(r=> r.Person);
```

Comment: This is incorrect. `ConvertAll` can't be called on the `IEnumerable<T>` result. What you *can* do is move the `ToList()` between the `Where` and `ConvertAll` calls.

Answer (score 6):

With *LINQ*, you can do:

```
positions.Where(r => r.Person != null)
         .Select(r => r.Person)
         .ToList();
```

The [`ConvertAll`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/73fe8cwf.aspx) method is not part of LINQ; it's an instance method on `List<T>`.
If you want to stick with that, you can do:

```
positions.FindAll(r => r.Person != null)
         .ConvertAll(r => r.Person);
```

Do note that this is subtly different because the result of the filter *and* the projection are both `List<T>`s, rather than streaming queries. The final result should be the same though.

Answer (score 2):

Use `Where` to filter out the null occurrences then use `Select`:

```
people = positions.Where(p => p.Person != null).Select(r => r.Person).ToList();
```